# With Ruby: how can I test to see if a linux command is available without returning the output of the command I'm testing for?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby on Linux.
I'd like to test for the existence of a command on the Linux system.

I'd like to *not* get back the output of the command that I'm testing for.

I'd also like to *not* get back any output that results from the shell being unable to find the command.

I want to avoid using shell redirection from within the command that I send to the shell. So something like system("foo > /dev/null") would be unsuitable.

I'm ok with using redirection if there is a way to do it from Ruby.

Comment: What do you mean by "is available"? 1. Is installed somewhere on the machine or 2. Is in the $PATH ? If 2. => which $PATH / env / shell / user?
You see, it's not that easy to think about that question without shells.
If you just need to know if some command is executable, do sth like `system("which foobar")`

Comment: Either. I just want to know if the command is available to be called from Ruby. Whether it's installed but not in the path doesn't matter. Unfortunately I can't use something like system("which foobar") because it returns the output of "which foobar". I don't want the return value of the command. I want to *not* have the output of the command.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing would be just to use `system`. Let's say you're looking for `ls`.

```
irb(main):005:0> system("which ls")
/bin/ls
=> true
```

If that's off the table, you could peek into the directories in `ENV["PATH"]` for the executable you're looking for. `ENV["PATH"].split(":")` would give you an array of directory names to check for the desired command. If you find a file with the right name, you may want to ensure it's an executable.

Comment: The problem with using system("which ls") is that it returns the shells response to "which ls", as illustrated in your example. I don't want that response. If I understand your suggestion of using ENV, I think that could work. But doesn't it seem a little unwieldy? Essentially I'd be doing a kind of grep against the returned filename of every executable in the path.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to avoid using shell redirection from within the command that I
> send to the shell. So something like system("foo > /dev/null") would
> be unsuitable.  I'm ok with using redirection if there is a way to do it from Ruby.

```
system("exec which cmd", out: "/dev/null")
puts "Command is available." if ($?).success?
```

The `exec` is to explicitly avoid unnecessary forking in the shell.

As a sidenote `type -P` can be used instead of `which`, but it relies on Bash and may have surprising effects if script is ported to an environment with a different default shell.